# Inverting Pixel Value of CSS Variable

Tags: css, css-variables

I'm using CSS variables, so that I can easily make sweeping changes. One of my variables is `--gap: 15px`, which I've used roughly 15 times so far. However, I now need to use the inverted value of `--gap`, which would be `-15px`.

*Fails:*

1. `calc(0 - var(--gap))`
2. `calc(var(--gap) * -1)`

*Works:*

3. `calc(var(--gap) - calc(var(--gap) * 2))`

*Questions:*

- The first attempt is clearly the most eloquent, but why doesn't work?
- Is there a way to achieve this that is more eloquent than the third way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first failure example works for me if I add units to the `0` part of the calculation.

From the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-type-checking):

> Note: Because <number-token>s are always interpreted as numbers or
>   <integer>s, "unitless 0" <length>s aren’t supported in calc(). That
>   is, width: calc(0 + 5px); is invalid, even though both width: 0; and
>   width: 5px; are valid.

```css
:root {
  --gap: 15px;
}

div {
  margin-top: calc(0px - var(--gap));
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Your second failure example is working for me.

```css
:root {
  --gap: 15px;
}

div {
  margin-top: calc(var(--gap) * -1);
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

I tested both examples in Firefox 64, Chrome 71, and Safari 12 (all Mac).

Comment: wth now the `2.` is working for me too... that is super strange. i was using Chrome 71 before too, unless it updated when i shut it down then?